# Merging existing localstorage item with state for a shoppingcart

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I got a situation where I do not have the experience to know which method is the best and what im doing wrong. The situation is as following:

I got a page with products which have a input + order button, which will add the order to the shoppingcart. My thought was to first set the state for each order you make:

```
const [amountItem, setAmountItem] = useState({
        product: {
            id: '',
            amount: ''
        }
    });
```

Updating:

```
function handleChange(evt, id) {
        const value = evt.currentTarget.value;

        setAmountItem({
            ...amountItem,
            product:{
                id: id,
                amount: value
            }
        });

        console.log(amountItem);
    }
```

Which  then I push to the shoppingcart/checkout page (no modal):

```
if (e.target[0].value < productItem.stock) {
                history.push({
                    pathname: `/winkelwagen/`,
                    state: {data: amountItem}
                });
```

On this page, i first check if location.state exists before using the shoppingcart component:

```
 if (location.state !== null && shoppingCartItems === '') {
        console.log(location.state.data);
        setShoppingCartItems(location.state.data);
        setShoppingCartActive(true);

        let cartString = JSON.stringify(shoppingCartItems);
        localStorage.setItem('shopping_carts', cartString)
    }
```

When it does exist, some product is ordered with an amount and must be set to localstorage, the product is 'always' visible when refreshing, etc. Until this point it works, the localstorage item exists:

```
(key)shopping_carts   (value){"product":{"id":3,"amount":"2"}}
```

After that comes the shoppingcart component:

```
 <ShoppingCart
    shoppingCartItems={shoppingCartItems}
    setShoppingCartItems={setShoppingCartItems}
    shoppingCartActive={shoppingCartActive}
    setShoppingCartActive={setShoppingCartActive}
 />
```

This is where my problem starts. Long story short, it only shows the single item from the state, which obviously will be gone.

In this file I got a useEffect part for the localstorage:

```
useEffect(() =>{
        let shoppingCart = localStorage.getItem("shopping_carts");
        console.log('shoppingcartitems ');
        shoppingCart = JSON.parse(shoppingCart);
        console.log(shoppingCart);

        if (shoppingCart !== "") {
             const id = shoppingCartItems.id;
             const amount = shoppingCartItems.amount;

            //setShoppingCartItems(shoppingCart)
            setShoppingCartItems(prevState => ({
                ...prevState,
                product: {
                    ...shoppingCartItems,
                    id: id,
                    amount: amount
                }
            }))
        }
    }, [setShoppingCartItems])
```

The output for 'shoppingCart' is `<empty string>`. Why is that? Is the format wrong? I'm also using the localstorage for other info, which works fine. I know the setShoppingCartItems is not correct for multiple values, but I wanted to test this single entry first.

Update:

```
const CheckoutPage = () => {
    const location = useLocation();

    const [shoppingCartItems, setShoppingCartItems] = useState('');
    const [shoppingCartActive, setShoppingCartActive] = useState(false);
    const [mode, setMode] = useState('init');

    let savedShoppingCart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("shopping_carts"));
    console.log('saved shopping cart: ')
    console.log(savedShoppingCart);

    if (savedShoppingCart !== "" && mode === 'init') {
        const id = savedShoppingCart.id;
        const amount = savedShoppingCart.amount;

        //setShoppingCartItems(shoppingCart)
        setShoppingCartItems(prevState => ({
            ...prevState,
            product: {
                ...shoppingCartItems,
                id: id,
                amount: amount
            }
        }))
        setMode('data');
        //setShoppingCartActive(true);
    }

    if (location.state !== null && shoppingCartItems === '') {
        console.log(location.state.data);
        setShoppingCartItems(location.state.data);
        setShoppingCartActive(true);

        let cartString = JSON.stringify(shoppingCartItems);
        localStorage.setItem('shopping_carts', cartString)
    }



    return (
        <div className="shoppingCartPage">
            <ShoppingCart
                shoppingCartItems={shoppingCartItems}
                setShoppingCartItems={setShoppingCartItems}
                shoppingCartActive={shoppingCartActive}
                setShoppingCartActive={setShoppingCartActive}
            />
        </div>

    )
}
```

So basically I want to do 3 things here:

- Get the data from the localstorage item
- Is there a saved localstorage item? Add it to existing shoppingCartItems (prevstate)
- Save the updated (or new when no localstorage item exists) shoppingCartItems after that

After that I want to pass the data to the shoppingcart where i can increase/decrease items or remove/splice the values.

Comment: What is showing your localStorage tab? It can be found at F12 -> Application -> Local Storage -> App url.  Be sure that what you are saving is saved and has the right format.

Comment: I see the local item like the 5th code block in my post above. Saved in JSON format and parsed on the getitem.

Answer (score 0):

Treat `useEffect` with caution as an `eventListener` on React state.

Therefore you need to specify in the dependency array everything might change, in order to trigger the `useEffect` callback.

In your `useEffect` dependencies, where you are updating your `shoppingCartItems`, you have added only `setShoppingCartItems` - which I assume that its a `setState` function. This results in your `useEffect` te be called only once at the app start because `setState` functions never change.

So, to have your `shoppingCartItems` updated via `useEffect` you need to add it to dependencies.

```
useEffect(() => {
    // your code
}, [setShoppingCartItems, shoppingCartItems])
```

This may fix your problem, because you never call logic that saves update shopping cart state, the second time, therefore you get empty in your console log.

Comment: Well, specific this part should only be called once. Because I only want to fetch the localstorageitems once. But another function in this component checks if shoppingCartItems has data and then fetches the product details by ID with axios (also useEffect, but without dependency). 

The shoppingCartItems either get set by: 

setShoppingCartItems(location.state.data);

Or in that function.

When I try to fetch the localstorage data in the checkoutpage it does work.

Comment: Can you show the code that gets data from localStorage?

Comment: I've changed my code and posted an update above

Comment: I see, where is the problem I see like it should be working? There is a lot of code but it's hard to understand what is wrong. Write it like this e.g: I want to have a, b, c. But with this code, I get only a.

Comment: From the help with a JS teacher I decided to take a step back and first let everything work with just 1 item, which works now.